# Python | Loop statement to creat file for every sheet in excel file

Tags: python, excel

I am fairly new to python and am trying to figure out how i can export data from every sheet in an excel workbook in to a different file for every sheet.

For example, in the first workbook, every sheet has data from a different brand; lets call this file my allbrandsmasterlist excel file.  I also have a perbrandbreakdown file which is the template i want every brand to pasted in to but with a different file for every brand.

In summary, I want to copy all the contents of every brand in to a new finalbrand file which keeps the same template from perbrandbreakdown but has automatically moved the data from each brand in the allbrandsmasterlist sheet in to its own file. The end result should be 1 file for every sheet/brand in the first file.

I have made some progress but i need help cleaning up this code and making it run the loop for all sheets in the first file where as now it is just running it once and only creates the file for the first brand ( only file output is for brand0 or first sheet). Thanks in advance and let me know if i can clear up any confusion

## here are the latest changes

```
       #import excel writing and reading modules
import xlwt
import xlrd
file = 'i:/My Client Data/CLASSHOG FINAL TEMPLATES AND FILES/item master new august.xlsx'
workbook1 = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
print ('There are %s sheets in %s'% (workbook1.nsheets,file))
"""for i in range(workbook.nsheets):
    print(i)"""


for i in range(workbook1.nsheets):
    if workbook1.nsheets > 1:
        workbookwt = xlwt.Workbook()
        sheet1 = workbookwt.add_sheet('ITEM DETAILS')


        #open template file to copy from
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('I:\My Client Data\CLASSHOG FINAL TEMPLATES AND FILES/PERFORMANCE MACHINE.xlsx')

        #set current sheet to first one in workbook
        sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

        #declare contents of rows individually -  manual
        datarow0 = [sheet.cell_value(0, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)]
        datarow1 = [sheet.cell_value(1, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)]
        datarow2 = [sheet.cell_value(2, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)]
        datarow3 = [sheet.cell_value(3, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)]
        datarow4 = [sheet.cell_value(4, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)]


        #declare contents of columns individually -  manual
        datacolA = [sheet.cell_value(row,0) for row in range(sheet.nrows)]
        datacolB = [sheet.cell_value(row,1) for row in range(sheet.nrows)]


        #number of worksheets, columns and rows respectively
        print("The number of worksheets is %s:" % (workbook.nsheets))
        print("The number of columns is %s:" % (sheet.ncols))
        print("The number of rows is %s:" % (sheet.nrows))

        #add first sheet and paste columns-manual


        for index, value in enumerate(datarow0):
            sheet1.write(0, index, value)


        for index, value in enumerate(datarow1):  
            sheet1.write(1, index, value)

        for index, value in enumerate(datarow2):
            sheet1.write(2, index, value)

        for index, value in enumerate(datarow3):
            sheet1.write(3, index, value) 
        #----------------------------------------------------

        sheet = workbookwt.add_sheet('CLEAN FILE')

        sheetswb1 = workbook1.sheet_by_index(i)
        datarow0 = [sheetswb1.cell_value(0, col) for col in range(sheetswb1.ncols)]
        datarow1 = [sheetswb1.cell_value(1, col) for col in range(sheetswb1.ncols)]

        for r in range(sheetswb1.nrows):
            for c in range(sheetswb1.ncols):
               sheet.write(r, c, sheetswb1.cell_value(r, c))


        #for index, value in enumerate(datarow0):
        #sheet.write(0, index, value)

        #for index, value in enumerate(datarow1):
        #sheet.write(1, index, value)
        #----------------------------------------------------

        sheet = workbookwt.add_sheet('SC FILE')
        sheet3 = workbook.sheet_by_index(2)

        #----------------------------------------------------

        sheet = workbookwt.add_sheet('EBAY FILE')
        sheet4 = workbook.sheet_by_index(3)

        #----------------------------------------------------
        sheet = workbookwt.add_sheet('PRICING STRATEGY')
        sheet5 = workbook.sheet_by_index(4)
        datarow0 = [sheet5.cell_value(0, col) for col in range(sheet5.ncols)]
        datarow1 = [sheet5.cell_value(1, col) for col in range(sheet5.ncols)]
        datarow2 = [sheet5.cell_value(2, col) for col in range(sheet5.ncols)]



        for index, value in enumerate(datarow0):
            sheet.write(0, index, value)

        for index, value in enumerate(datarow1):
            sheet.write(1, index, value)

        for index, value in enumerate(datarow2):
            sheet.write(2, index, value)



        workbookwt.save('i:/pythonvirioutput/output%s.xls' % ("brand" + str(i)))
        print('Operation run and file saved for brand' + str(i))



    else: print('The workbook has less than 2 sheets')
    break
```

## output

```
There are 441 sheets in i:/My Client Data/CLASSHOG FINAL TEMPLATES AND FILES/item master new august.xlsx
The number of worksheets is 5:
The number of columns is 2:
The number of rows is 5:
Operation run and file saved for brand0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be only working , because you get the current sheet as -

```
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
```

You are only getting the first sheet, always, hence it always only writes out the data from the first sheet, you should instead use `i` here, to get each sheet separately. Code -

```
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(i)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt feedback! Unfortunately changing the sheet to i still gives me the same result :/

Comment: Are you 100% sure about it? you tried with `i`? Do the sheet's have any difference?

Comment: Can you please try printing the data being saved/read from the sheet and check if its still the wrong sheet being picked up?

Comment: added output to an edit i made put ill print it here as well: There are 441 sheets in i:/My Client Data/CLASSHOG FINAL TEMPLATES AND FILES/item master new august.xlsx
The number of worksheets is 5:
The number of columns is 2:
The number of rows is 5:
Operation run and file saved for brand0

Comment: anand i need it to copy the data from the each sheet on the first file which is being opened before the for loop. if i change that to an i wont it do the script for every sheet in the second file?

Comment: Which file do you want to copy from? Seems like within the loop , you are overriding `workbook` with a new excel? in line - `workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('I:\My Client Data\CLASSHOG FINAL TEMPLATES AND FILES/PERFORMANCE MACHINE.xlsx')` .

Comment: Try removing that line and check. Also do not override `workbook` name with anything else anywhere, always use different variable names.

Comment: anand you are correct, i want to copy data from 2 places. The sheet for every brand from the first file and everything in the loop for the other 4 sheets. It is starting to seem that maybe i do not have the code written that copies the data from the first sheet? Thank you again!

Comment: so one sheet = one brand from the first file plus 4 sheets from the second file which makes the 5 sheets in the output file

Comment: Oh ok, then you need to use `i` for reading from the first sheet, not second sheet.

Comment: ok i think i was missing the read and write commands from the first file because i was doing it in the second. i moved it around and am running it now and will let you know

Comment: i made some changes to the first 20 lines which i have added to my post. I am still getting an error which i also posted

Comment: Like I said use different names, you are using `sheet` for all the sheets, its rewriting the writable sheet with a read only sheet. PLease do not use the exact same variable name everywhere.

Comment: ok i changed the name and it ran with no errors but i still only output one file. i am posting the changes now

Comment: Also show the part where you are writing the data and saving the worksheet?

Comment: You are never using the sheet from the actual xl - `sheetswb1` anywhere, use it where you want to use it.

Comment: sorry this is my first python script. thanks i am running it again to see what happens, will update shortly

Comment: it looks like ive made some progress as it is now copying from both files but it is still only outputting data for the first sheet and outputting 1 file. 

also, do you know how i could copy all rows instead of only the ones ive defined? i imageine i have to change the lines to include .ncols or .nrows but im not too sure. I updated the new code and added the rows being defined manually at the bottom of the post

Comment: I have already answered that in your other question, check out my answer there.

Comment: just saw your response thanks so much. only original problem i have left with this question now is the outputting of only 1 file instead of 1 per sheet

Comment: Can you check if datarow0 is correctly getting populated? Also do one thing, print the value of `i` at the start of the loop?

Comment: Meaning check if the first row is correctly the row from the first sheet in your actual excel , it may be getting overwritten somehwere?

Comment: yes i have checked the output file and the correct data is getting pasted in to the template sheet but it is only running the script for the first sheet.

updating the code in post now

Comment: Ok, finally see the issue, remove the `break` at the end of the for loop? WHY do you have that there?

Comment: when i print i at the start of the loop i get 0

Comment: oh my god i dont know i put it there i dont know why but it is working now you are AMAZING

I will NEVER forget you this is literally the first python script ever written and its 730 am here. This is the start of my dev career thanks you you!